# Store Hours Plugin - Output Details

Tags: plugins

Anyone using the "Store Hours" plugin know how to print out day open and close hours details?

I have tried this but not outputting anything.

```
{% for openTime in entry.openTimes %}
    {{openTime.day.open}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Note: openTimes is a field of StoreHours type.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you reached out the to plugin developer? Is there a link (github or otherwise) for this plugin?

Comment: Pixel and Tonic are the developers of this plugin. I thought this is the best place to ask. On the github page there is no info about outputting in twig template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `openTime` data is being stored as a numerically-indexed array. You may even want to create a mapping of those days to make rendering each day easier:

```
{% set days = {
    0: 'Sunday',
    1: 'Monday',
    2: 'Tuesday',
    3: 'Wednesday',
    4: 'Thursday',
    5: 'Friday',
    6: 'Saturday'
} %}
```

Then you can adjust your `for` loop like this:

```
{% for dayIndex,openTime in entry.openTimes %}

    {% set day = days[dayIndex] %}
    {% set hours = openTime.open|date('g:i a') ~ ' - ' ~ openTime.close|date('g:i a') %}

    {{ day }}: {{ hours }}<br/>

{% endfor %}
```

**Pro Tip:**

If you have [dev mode](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/dev-mode) enabled, you can use `dump` to see what a variable contains.

```
{{ dump(anyVariable) }}
```

That's how I figured out the underlying structure of the `openTime` data.

Answer (score 6):

Following from Lindsey D's answer, I just wanted to point out you can skip manually mapping the weekday names by calling `craft.i18n.getLocaleData().getWeekDayName()` like so:

```
{% set day = craft.i18n.getLocaleData().getWeekDayName(dayIndex) %}
```

It's also worth mentioning, you can check for empty values to indicate the store is closed.

E.g.,

```
{% for dayIndex,dayHours in companyInfo.storeHours %}

  {% set day = craft.i18n.getLocaleData().getWeekDayName(dayIndex) %}

  {{day}}: {{ (dayHours.open is empty) ? 'CLOSED' : dayHours.open|date('g:i a') ~ '-' ~ dayHours.close|date('g:i a') }}

  <br>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get {% set day = craft.i18n.getLocaleData().getWeekDayName(dayIndex) %} to start on Monday instead of Sunday?